# SQL Server : Remote Linked Oracle DB Query to include ROWID?

Tags: sql-server, plsql, migration

I am not too familiar with how the linked remote databases work in SQL Server. But I am trying to query to a linked remote oracle database table using SQL syntax on SQL Server. I am having a issue trying to query a `ROWID`, which is proprietary to Oracle PL/SQL.

This is query I am trying to use:

```
select t.*, t.rowid 
from owner.DMIS_TBL t
```

Is there a way to input a Oracle based query in SQL Server for a remote database? Querying all other columns in the Oracle tables works fine but if I specify the `ROWID` it does not recognize it.. I know the `ROWID` this is a pseudo column but I need to have this for migration purposes to use as the record id in SQL Server. Maybe it won't work in SQL syntax because the datatype is `ROWID` and SQL Server doesn't support this.

Comment: Got it. OPENQUERY in SQL allows for PLSQL passthrough..

Comment: Syntax is 'OPENQUERY ( linked_server ,'query' )' for anyone wondering how to do it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx